# Speed of swapping elements in a doubly linked list Vs a singly list

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I wrote two functions:

```
swapsingle(): swaps elements in a singly linked list
swapdouble(): swaps elements in a doubly linked list
```

But the book I am reading (Data Structures and Algorithms in Python - Michael H. Goldwasser, Michael T. Goodrich, and Roberto Tamassia) says that the swapping in a doubly linked list should be faster than the one in a singly linked list. But when I time both functions swapdouble() is slower

Here are my two single and double linked classes:

```
    class SingleLL:
        """ Singly Linked List Class """ 
        # Nested _Node class
        class _Node:
            __slots__ = '_element', '_next'
    
            def __init__(self, element, next):
                self._element = element
                self._next = next
        
        def __init__(self):
            """ Create an empty Stack"""
            self._head = None # Reference to the Head node
            self._size = 0
        
        def __len__(self):
            """ Returns the number of elements in the stack"""
            return self._size
        
           
        def push(self, e):
            """ Add element e to the top of the stack"""
            self._head = self._Node(e, self._head)
            self._size += 1
        
        def __str__(self):
            """ Printing a Linked List"""
            # defining a blank result variable
            result = ""
            # initialising the printer to head
            printer = self._head
            
            # traversing and adding it to result
            while printer:
                result += str(printer._element) + ", "
                printer = printer._next
            
            # removing the trailing comma
            result = result.strip(', ')
            
            # before printing we check if the list is empty or not
            if len(result):
                return "[" + result + "]"
            else:
                return "[]"
            
    class DoubleLL:
        """A base class providing a doubly linked list representation"""
        
        class _Node:
            """Lighweight, non-public class for storing a doubly linked node."""
            __slots__ = '_element', '_prev', '_next'
    
            def __init__(self, element, prev, next):
                self._element = element
                self._prev = prev
                self._next = next
                
        def __init__(self):
            """ Create an empty list"""
            self._header = self._Node(None,None,None)
            self._trailer = self._Node(None, None, None)
            self._header._next = self._trailer
            self._trailer._prev = self._header
            self._size = 0
        
        def __len__(self):
            return self._size
        
           
        def _insert_between(self,e, predecessor, successor):
            """ Add element e between two existing nodes and return new node."""
            newest = self._Node(e,predecessor,successor)
            predecessor._next = newest
            successor._prev = newest
            self._size += 1
            #return newest
        
           
        def push(self, e):
            """ Add element e to the front of the list"""
            self._insert_between(e,self._header, self._header._next)
            
        
        def __str__(self):
            """ Printing a Linked List"""
            # defining a blank result variable
            result = ""
            # initialising the printer to head
            printer = self._header
            
            # traversing and adding it to result
            while printer:
                result += str(printer._element) + ", "
                printer = printer._next
            
            # removing the trailing comma
            result = result.strip(', ')
            
            # before printing we check if the list is empty or not
            if len(result):
                return "[" + result + "]"
            else:
                return "[]"
```

and here is the code for my two functions with a test case and timing:

```
    def swapsingle(L,a,b):
        if a == b:
            return
        else:
            # let's look for the node with 'a' as an element
            preva = None
            loca = L._head
            while loca._next != None and loca._element != a:
                preva = loca
                loca = loca._next
            # let's look for the node with 'b' as an element
            prevb = None
            locb = L._head
            while locb._next != None and locb._element != b:
                prevb = locb
                locb = locb._next
            # if either 'a' or 'b' is not on the linked list, do nothing
            if loca == None or locb == None:
                return
            # if 'a' is not the head of the list
            if preva != None:
                preva._next = locb
            else:
                L._head = locb
            # if 'b' is not the head of the list
            if prevb != None:
                prevb._next = loca
            else:
                L._head = loca
            
            # swap next pointers
            temp = loca._next
            loca._next = locb._next
            locb._next = temp
    
    def swapdouble(L,a,b):
        if a == b:
            return
        else:
            # let's look for 'a'
            loca = L._header
            while loca._next != None and loca._element != a:
                loca = loca._next
            # let's look for 'b'
            locb = L._header
            while locb._next != None and locb._element != b:
                locb = locb._next
            # if either 'a' or 'b' are not on the list, do nothing
            if loca == None or locb == None:
                return
            
            # change prev
            temp = loca._prev
            loca._prev = locb._prev
            locb._prev._next = loca
            locb._prev = temp
            temp._next = locb
            
            # change next
            temp = loca._next
            loca._next = locb._next
            locb._next._prev = loca
            locb._next = temp
            temp._prev = loca
            
    
            
    L = SingleLL()
    for i in range(1,5):
        L.push(i)
    print(L)
    %timeit swapsingle(L,1,3)
    print(L)
    D = DoubleLL()
    for i in range(1,5):
        D.push(i)
    print(D)
    %timeit swapdouble(D,1,3)
    print(D)
```

Here is my output:

```
[4, 3, 2, 1]
844 ns ± 10.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
[4, 1, 2, 3]
[None, 4, 3, 2, 1, None]
1.12 µs ± 2.83 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
[None, 4, 1, 2, 3, None]
```

Can you please explain to me why my doubleswap is slower than singleswap, and why it should be faster in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the statement speaks about swapping two nodes given only references to the nodes, not their values (which may not even be unique). Then it's fairly obvious: In case of doubly-linked list, you have pointers to both predecesors and succesors of the swapped nodes, so you can just swap them. In case of singly-linked list you first have to iterate through the list to find the predecessors.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now!